# How do you set up DNS in Window Server 2008 in a Hyper-V environment?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, hyper-v

I have a laptop running Server 2008 and Hyper-V.  I have created a virtual machine that is also running Server 2008, that I used `dcpromo` to create as a domain controller.  I disabled IPv6 because I had no idea how to enter a default address, and I just wanted to make a standalone MOSS dev environment.  I have tried every combination of creating a virtual network on the host and then connecting to that in the VM, but I can't get the VM to communicate with the host and vice versa.  No pinging, no copy and paste, nothing.

Thanks.

To update: My VM (which is its own DC) currently does not have a static IP.  When I set the IP to static, I could not find anything that would let it talk to the host machine.

Comment: What type of virtual network are you using.  Can the VM see the NIC?

Comment: I'm using the "Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller - Virtual Network" set up using Hyper-V.  The VM sees that there is a NIC, but cannot communicate.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but I stumbled across this while searching for something else.

You said this is a laptop. One issue you may be running into is that I believe Hyper-V doesn't support wireless network cards. If the network card you are trying to use is your wireless one and not your ethernet one, that may be your issue.

I ran into a similar issue when trying to re-purpose an old laptop as a test machine.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings for the VM itself (as opposed to the networking settings in hyperV), does the ethernet port have the target network selected?  (this is a setting I seem very prone to forgetting to check/change)

Up to this point, I keep the host and guest on the same subnet, I'm not sure how well hyperV is going to NAT that out on its own?  Give the VM a static address on the same subnet as the DC to take DNS out of the picture and test basic "hardware" connectivity.

Comment: 1. The Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter (the only connection) is currently set to DHCP, but cannot get an address.

2. My VM is the DC, so I'm not quite sure what address to give it to test connectivity.

Comment: 1) Your DC has a static IP, so if you give your VM the next consecutive number (without getting into a long subnetting explanation), that'll be a good first test.  e.g. 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 -- that setting is in the guest OS itself

2) the other setting is under the hyper V role on the 2008 (host) server itself.  It would be in the settings for the VM object under Hyper V Manager.

Comment: That's my point - my DC is my VM.  My DC does not have a static IP.  I had to pick one to set up DNS, but I had no idea what to set it to.  I tried a number of addresses and none of them worked.